# Coupling of "Max of two uniform random variable" & "root of an uniform one"

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, random-variables, coupling

Consider $X,Y,Z \in [0,1]$ be three independent uniform random variables.

It's easy to show that $A=max\{X,Y\}$ and $B=\sqrt{Z}$ have same distribution.

But I want a direct proof that completely couples these two random variables without computing their distributions...

Has any one know any way to do this?

Comment: Are $X, Y, Z$ independent?

Comment: @ntt yeah. Done. But x,y is sufficient to be independent

Comment: You seem to be engaged in a vast campaign of minor edits to old questions. This brings nothing worthwhile to the site,but it bumps needlessly old questions with answers to the front page. Sure you cannot find more productive ways of contributing to the site?

Comment: @Did Can you couple these two random variables?

Comment: Huh? Related to the point raised by my comment?

Comment: @Did Yeah. It will be a good contribution to the site!

Comment: Wow. Constructiveness at its best.

Comment: @Did So, Do it.

Answer (score 1):

Consider sampling points in the unit square $ X \times Y$.

Then $A=\max\{X,Y\}$ is formed by the rule of taking the $y$-coordinate for points above the $y=x$ line and the $x$-coordinate for points below it.

Now consider the rule where we reject points in the upper triangle and consider only $x$-coordinates from the lower triangle. The (conditional) probability of getting an $x$ less than a given $a$ is ratio of the area of the triangle $[(0,0), (a,0), (a,a)]$ to the entire lower triangle $[(0,0), (1,0), (1,1)]$, which is simply $a^2$. The same is true of $y$ by symmetry for the upper triangle. But this is the same as the distribution for $\sqrt{Z}$:

$$F_{\sqrt{Z}}(a) = P(\sqrt{Z} < a) = P(Z < a^2) = a^2$$

[image: $ X \times Y$]

Figure: Lines illustrate the rule for $A = \max\{X,Y\}$. Shading illustrates calculation of probability for $\sqrt{Z}$.

Comment: Thanks but as you mentioned this is not what I'm looking for

Comment: We can appeal to simple geometry here rather than the rejection sampling argument, as edited.

Comment: @A.Webb Coupling $\neq$ rejection sampling, btw